# How to begin creating 3D (Game-) GUIs for Android Applications (e.g. with OpenGL)?

Tags: java, android, 3d, opengl-es

I am new to Android Development. What I want is to know how I have to begin thinking to program a neat, GUI. I guess the android.opengl API is a good starting point.

Let's say we want to create something like a simplified 3D-Pool-Billard-Game: You see the table from the top and you have on the table the balls. You want to make them realistic (shadow, gloss).

Questions on my mind are:

- What kind of Graphics do I need?
- How to begin coding?
- What kind of classes do I need? For each element (ball, table, ..)?
- Where to create and encapsulate the "3D-ness"?

If you know better/additional questions, just add them or/and let me know in which direction I have to think in this case of developing.

My skills/background on Java: I've programmed a lot in Java EE and used to handle graphical output with JSP/JSF. So this mobile SE for Android is new to me. Hope to get some intersting stuff together for a smooth access.

Chris

Comment: I think a good start point would be [GoogleIO 2010 presentation by Chris Pruett](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk).

Comment: FYI, Android uses [OpenGL ES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES), not regular OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recomend using a existing 3d engine, else your in for *a lot* of work.
http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/  isn't a bad one and has a flexible license.

Comment: IMHO jPCT-AE is the best for pure java game development on android. With jBrush-AE you can create & load game scene on the fly.